# How to bulk INSERT to a table with a loop in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

To test a report against data, I want to INSERT test data into a table in Postgres SQL.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO call_logs (phonenumber,timeofcall) VALUES ('+12121001001','2014-12-23T07:01:00.000+00:00')
```

But I want to loop, say, 59 times, to have phone numbers 2121001001, 1002, 1003, etc with times of call 07:01, 07:02, 07:03, etc.

How do I do that with a loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a loop. Use [`generate_series`:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)

```
insert into call_logs (column1, phonenumber,timeofcall)
select
    'constant_value',
    '+' || generate_series(12121001001, 12121001059),
    generate_series(
        '2014-12-23t07:01:00.000+00:00'::timestamp,
        '2014-12-23t07:59:00.000+00:00',
        '1 minute'
    )
```

Comment: Will that increase the phone number too? 212-100-1001, 212-100-1002, etc. And also, I left a few columns out for simplicity, but I do have a few other columns that will not change the value, though. How will the SQL statement be then? Thanks.

Comment: [A few things to be wary about when using `generate_series()` in a select statement](http://www.mesoconcepts.com/2013/06/inconsistent-unnesting-in-postgresql/).